# Difference between functions and properties in Vala

Tags: properties, vala

New to Vala here... trying to understand the difference between properties and getters/setters.

```
public class Person {
  public string name {
    get {
      XPath.NodeSet* nodes = search (node, "/name");
      return nodes->item (0)->get_content (); 
    }
  }

  public string get_name() {
    XPath.NodeSet* nodes = search (node, "/name");
    return nodes->item (0)->get_content (); 
  }
}
```

The second `get_name ()` function works as expected. The property does not. It throws:

```
Return value transfers ownership but function return type hasn't been declared to transfer ownership
      return nodes->item (0)->get_content (); 
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What am I missing here? Is the `get_content ()` not returning a string or does the function solution do some conversion magic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, functions return owned values (caller must free), but property getters return unowned values (caller must not free). So, the memory returned by `get_context ()` will be deallocated and a dangling pointer returned. The values properties return need to either be backed by values that are owned elsewhere (*e.g.*, in a field) or change the return type to be owned so Vala will make a copy of the value.

Comment: Thanks, I get it know. I need a "class variable" (in Ruby parlance) to keep the value in memory!

Comment: No. Class variables in Ruby are static variables in Vala. It can be a field (instance variable), class variable, constant, or any of those from another class.